# Adding user control to ASP.NET webform, but don't want it to declare itself in designer file

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Does anybody know if it's possible to add a user control to a web form in Visual Studio 2008, but to not have its declaration added to the designer file?

Comment: You mean, you want to add it in code?

Comment: No, I mean I want the only reference to this user control to be in the .aspx file, not the .cs or .designer.cs files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my issue was to develop the form outside of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the path of the control (either programatically or from DB/config) you can do

```
Page.Controls.Add("pathToYourControl");
```

Comment: Make sure to add the control in the Page_Init event, not the Page_Load.

Comment: That sounds good, but I would like a way I can add/remove/modify the user control from the .aspx file on the web server, and not have to recompile and redeploy.

Comment: Have it in a config file. Then

`foreach(Control c in ControlsReadFromConfig)
{
Page.Controls.Add(c);
}`

Comment: where will it place that control?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use [Page.LoadControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page?view=netframework-4.8.1), examples in both links:

```
void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Instantiate the UserControl object
    MyControl myControl1 =
        (MyControl)LoadControl("TempControl_Samples1.ascx.cs");
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myControl1);
}
```

[A Good Example of Asp.net LoadControl with multiple parameters](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202094005/http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2006/03/23/73096.aspx)

Comment: I need the reference to the usercontrol in the markup so it can be moved, removed, modified.